# How can I set up a proxy to get the requests from selenium using Browsermob::Proxy in perl?

Tags: selenium, perl, proxy

I have been the whole day working on this and this and I got a little bit frustrated for not being able to make it work.

I started using a standalone selenium server as follows:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\some_path\chromedriver.exe" -jar "C:\some_path\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar"
```

Then I downloaded the `browsermob-proxy-2.1.4` and just executed the `./bin/browsermob-proxy.bat`

Then I battled for some hours to find the properties in chrome that would not complain because I am using a proxy and showed the exception `NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`:

So I ended up with this code:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

use Browsermob::Proxy;
use Browsermob::Server;

use Selenium::Remote::Driver;
use Selenium::Waiter qw/wait_until/;




my $server = Browsermob::Server->new(
    server_port => 8080
);

my $proxy = $server->create_proxy;

my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new('browser_name' =>'chrome',
                                            proxy   => $proxy->selenium_proxy(1),
                                           'extra_capabilities' => {
                                               'goog:chromeOptions' => {
                                                   'args'  => [
                                                       'ignore-ssl-errors=yes',
                                                       'proxy-auto-detect',
                                                   ],
                                                   'prefs' => {
                                                    'profile' => {
                                                        'accept_ssl_certs' => 'true',
                                                        'accept_insecure_certs' => 'true',
                                                    },
                                                    'session' => {
                                                           'restore_on_startup' => 4,
                                                           'urls_to_restore_on_startup' => [
                                                               'http://www.google.com',
                                                               'http://docs.seleniumhq.org'
                                                           ]},
                                                       'first_run_tabs' => [
                                                           'http://www.google.com',
                                                           'http://docs.seleniumhq.org'
                                                       ]
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           });



$proxy->create_new_har(
    payload => {
        initialPageRef => 'payload is optional'
    },
    captureHeaders => 'true',
    captureContent => 'true',
    captureBinaryContent => 'true'
);

print("Getting stackoverflow\n");
wait_until{$driver->get("https://www.stackoverflow.com")};
validate_site($driver);


sleep(20);
$driver->quit;

sub validate_site{
    my ($driver) = @_;
    
    print "Har:\n";
    print Dumper($proxy->har);
}
```

But now I just get the following output, which looks like if the proxy would not capture anything:

```
Getting stackoverflow
Har:
$VAR1 = {
          'log' => {
                     'creator' => {
                                    'version' => '2.1.4',
                                    'name' => 'BrowserMob Proxy',
                                    'comment' => ''
                                  },
                     'entries' => [],
                     'version' => '1.2',
                     'comment' => '',
                     'pages' => [
                                  {
                                    'comment' => '',
                                    'pageTimings' => {
                                                       'comment' => ''
                                                     },
                                    'startedDateTime' => '2020-10-01T18:21:20.171+02:00',
                                    'id' => 'Page 0',
                                    'title' => 'Page 0'
                                  }
                                ]
                   }
        };
```

What is funny, is that if I comment the line autodected proxy, I get the following:

```
Getting stackoverflow
Har:
$VAR1 = {
          'log' => {
                     'pages' => [
                                  {
                                    'comment' => '',
                                    'id' => 'Page 0',
                                    'title' => 'Page 0',
                                    'startedDateTime' => '2020-10-01T18:19:15.850+02:00',
                                    'pageTimings' => {
                                                       'comment' => ''
                                                     }
                                  }
                                ],
                     'entries' => [
                                    {
                                      'serverIPAddress' => 'some_ip',
                                      'startedDateTime' => '2020-10-01T18:19:15.900+02:00',
                                      'response' => {
                                                      'comment' => '',
                                                      'status' => 0,
                                                      'headers' => [],
                                                      'content' => {
                                                                     'comment' => '',
                                                                     'size' => 0,
                                                                     'mimeType' => ''
                                                                   },
                                                      'bodySize' => -1,
                                                      'statusText' => '',
                                                      'cookies' => [],
                                                      'redirectURL' => '',
                                                      'httpVersion' => 'unknown',
                                                      '_error' => 'Unable to connect to host',
                                                      'headersSize' => -1
                                                    },
                                      'pageref' => 'Page 0',
                                      'timings' => {
                                                     'connect' => 257,
                                                     'wait' => 0,
                                                     'ssl' => -1,
                                                     'receive' => 0,
                                                     'send' => 0,
                                                     'blocked' => 0,
                                                     'comment' => '',
                                                     'dns' => 0
                                                   },
                                      'time' => 258,
                                      'request' => {
                                                     'comment' => '',
                                                     'queryString' => [],
                                                     'cookies' => [],
                                                     'headers' => [],
                                                     'headersSize' => 0,
                                                     'bodySize' => 0,
                                                     'url' => 'https://www.stackoverflow.com',
                                                     'method' => 'CONNECT',
                                                     'httpVersion' => 'HTTP/1.1'
                                                   },
                                      'cache' => {},
                                      'comment' => ''
                                    },
                                    {
                                      'time' => 258,
                                      'cache' => {},
                                      'request' => {
                                                     'httpVersion' => 'HTTP/1.1',
                                                     'bodySize' => 0,
                                                     'headersSize' => 0,
                                                     'url' => 'https://www.stackoverflow.com',
                                                     'method' => 'CONNECT',
                                                     'headers' => [],
                                                     'cookies' => [],
                                                     'comment' => '',
                                                     'queryString' => []
                                                   },
                                      'comment' => '',
                                      'serverIPAddress' => 'some_ip',
                                      'response' => {
                                                      '_error' => 'Unable to connect to host',
                                                      'headersSize' => -1,
                                                      'httpVersion' => 'unknown',
                                                      'cookies' => [],
                                                      'redirectURL' => '',
                                                      'content' => {
                                                                     'size' => 0,
                                                                     'comment' => '',
                                                                     'mimeType' => ''
                                                                   },
                                                      'bodySize' => -1,
                                                      'statusText' => '',
                                                      'headers' => [],
                                                      'status' => 0,
                                                      'comment' => ''
                                                    },
                                      'startedDateTime' => '2020-10-01T18:19:15.900+02:00',
                                      'pageref' => 'Page 0',
                                      'timings' => {
                                                     'dns' => 0,
                                                     'blocked' => 0,
                                                     'comment' => '',
                                                     'receive' => 0,
                                                     'send' => 0,
                                                     'connect' => 257,
                                                     'wait' => 0,
                                                     'ssl' => -1
                                                   }
                                    },
                                    {
                                      'cache' => {},
                                      'request' => {
                                                     'cookies' => [],
                                                     'comment' => '',
                                                     'queryString' => [],
                                                     'httpVersion' => 'HTTP/1.1',
                                                     'bodySize' => 0,
                                                     'headersSize' => 344,
                                                     'url' => 'http://www.gstatic.com/generate_204',
                                                     'method' => 'GET',
                                                     'headers' => [
                                                                    {
                                                                      'name' => 'Host',
                                                                      'value' => 'www.gstatic.com'
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                      'name' => 'Proxy-Connection',
                                                                      'value' => 'keep-alive'
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                      'value' => 'no-cache',
                                                                      'name' => 'Pragma'
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                      'name' => 'Cache-Control',
                                                                      'value' => 'no-cache'
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                      'value' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
                                                                      'name' => 'User-Agent'
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                      'name' => 'Accept-Encoding',
                                                                      'value' => 'gzip, deflate'
                                                                    },
                                                                    {
                                                                      'value' => 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                                                                      'name' => 'Accept-Language'
                                                                    }
                                                                  ]
                                                   },
                                      'time' => 161,
                                      'comment' => '',
                                      'serverIPAddress' => 'some_ip',
                                      'timings' => {
                                                     'connect' => 46,
                                                     'ssl' => -1,
                                                     'wait' => 21,
                                                     'receive' => 38,
                                                     'send' => 1,
                                                     'blocked' => 0,
                                                     'comment' => '',
                                                     'dns' => 53
                                                   },
                                      'startedDateTime' => '2020-10-01T18:19:16.176+02:00',
                                      'response' => {
                                                      'cookies' => [],
                                                      'redirectURL' => '',
                                                      'comment' => '',
                                                      'status' => 204,
                                                      'headers' => [
                                                                     {
                                                                       'name' => 'Content-Length',
                                                                       'value' => '0'
                                                                     },
                                                                     {
                                                                       'value' => 'Thu, 01 Oct 2020 16:19:16 GMT',
                                                                       'name' => 'Date'
                                                                     }
                                                                   ],
                                                      'httpVersion' => 'HTTP/1.1',
                                                      'content' => {
                                                                     'comment' => '',
                                                                     'size' => 0,
                                                                     'encoding' => 'base64',
                                                                     'text' => '',
                                                                     'mimeType' => ''
                                                                   },
                                                      'bodySize' => 0,
                                                      'statusText' => 'No Content',
                                                      'headersSize' => 85
                                                    },
                                      'pageref' => 'Page 0'
                                    }
                                  ],
                     'creator' => {
                                    'name' => 'BrowserMob Proxy',
                                    'comment' => '',
                                    'version' => '2.1.4'
                                  },
                     'version' => '1.2',
                     'comment' => ''
                   }
        };
```

So although I get the exception in the browser and I can'T do anything with selenium it seems to work.

Anyone can give me a hint on what is going on?

Thank you!